# Jquery Carousel Previous slide

Tags: jquery

trying to work a simple Jquery Carousel with autoplay and arrows that scroll through the next and previous slides. The next slide code works fine but not the previous arrow. I don't know how to loop backwards through my images and fade in the previous one

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div><h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">This is the FIRST slider</h1></div>
        <div id="slide-1">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">This is the SECOND slider</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-2">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">This is the THIRD slider</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-3">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">This is the FOURTH slider</h1>
        </div>
        <div><h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">This is the LAST slider</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-div-1 show"><img src="images/arrow_left.svg" alt="" id="left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="arrow-div-2 show"><img src="images/arrow_right.svg" alt="" id="right-arrow"></div>
</div>







$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var intrvl = setInterval(function() { 
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);



$(".arrow-div-2").click(function(){
    clearInterval(intrvl)
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}) 

$(".arrow-div-1").click(function(){
    clearInterval(intrvl)
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .prev()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, got the answer! The second (left/previous) arrow div code should be this

```
    $(".arrow-div-1").click(function(){
    clearInterval(intrvl)
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slideshow > div:last")
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .prependTo('#slideshow');
})
```